# Unity bar changing colour without request

Tags: unity, themes, desktop-background, conky

**UPDATED: I found that this happenes whenever I run the sudo -i nautilus command.**

The Unity bar is changing colour without my request. I am not changing the background (I know it automatically adjusts to your wallpaper).

It is normally set to a dark orange which it gets from my wallpaper. But sometimes, it bugs out and switches to the default purple. This also messes up my conky configuration and creates a red background around the conky window (which is set to dock mode).

I was messing around and installed Gnome over top of Unity... and I've recently removed Gnome (not all of it though, login screen is still there for some reason) and I am wondering if the Gnome desktop change might have messed something up...

**Here you'll see the way it should look.**

[image]

**Here is what happens.**
Note that the conky goes red, and the Unity bar goes purple...
What can I do to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the launcher color to custom using the *unity-tweak-tool*.

**Edit:**
Installation: `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
Open it, then under *Unity* -> *Launcher* -> *Appearance* you can set the color to *Custom*.

Comment: can you please explain installation process and instructions to changes suggested (it'd serve every one in a better way)